# Using a controller as uibModal Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

So I am working on a module called "ShowTree". 
Before this, I have a controller named "InviteUserCtrl". Inside the ShowTree module, there is a button that will show a uibModal that is used to add new user.

Basically this uibModal in ShowTreeCtrl is all exactly the same as InviteUserCtrl. So, instead of copy pasting all the code from the InviteUserCtrl to the new uibModalController, I decided to inject the InviteUserCtrl as the uibModalController.

The problem is I can't use the InviteUserCtrl as my uibModalController

here is my html code in ShowTree list.html

```
<div ng-controller="inviteUserCtrl as vm">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="inviteUser.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
     <h3 class="modal-title">Invite User</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <span ng-include="'app_view/modules/invite_user/form.html'"></span>
      <br><br>
    </div> 
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="vm.cancel()">Back</button>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

here is the code in my ShowTreeCtrl

```
function open(size){
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
    animation : true,
    templateUrl: 'inviteUser.html',
    controller: 'inviteUserCtrl as vm',
    size: size,
});
}
```

Also i am using ui-router. here is my code in the router

```
.state('app.show_tree', {
url: '/show_tree/:action/:id',
templateUrl: base_view_url+'modules/show_tree/index.html',
data : { title: 'Show Tree' },
controller : "showTreeCtrl",
controllerAs : "vm",
resolve: load([
    base_view_url+'modules/show_tree/showTreeCtrl.js',
    base_view_url+'modules/invite_user/inviteUserCtrl.js',
    'ui.select'
]),
params : {action:"list",id:null},
activetab: 'Activity'
})
```

The above code is able to display the form from the InviteUser module, but the controller seems doesn't work. The form button and the controller API do not run at all.

What am I missing here? thank you ..